# Loading jquery library after using app.use sendFile

Tags: javascript, express

I am having trouble loading my jquery library so I can use it my file 'server.js'. Right now I have a file called 'route.js', that sends a file called 'home.html' on 'localhost:port/'. When the home.html will display, but I have a jquery cdn/library along with a link to server.js, but when I run node route.js, I keep getting a error message that states '$' is not defined, meaning my js file is running before the html finishes loading. How can I fix this problem?

//server.js

```
exports.path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
exports.app = express();

$(document).on('click', '.btn', sendSurvery);

function sendSurvey(){

    var myQueryUrl = "http://localhost:10003/survey";

    $.ajax({url: myQueryUrl, method: 'GET'});
}
```

//route.js

```
var library = require('../../server.js');

library.app.use(function(request, response){
    // response.sendFile(__dirname + '/../public/home.html');
    response.sendFile(library.path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/home.html'));
})

library.app.get('/survey', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(library.path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/survey.html'));
})

library.app.listen(10003, function(){
    console.log('connected on 10003')
})
```

//home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Friend Finder Home Page</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="rowOne">
        <div class="jumbotron col-lg-6">
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <p>Click the button NOW!</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">CLICK NOW!</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load your server code in the browser.

Try moving your js to a static file in your public folder and load that file form your html:

// survey.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.btn', sendSurvery);

    function sendSurvey(){

        var myQueryUrl = "http://localhost:10003/survey";

        $.ajax({url: myQueryUrl, method: 'GET'});
    }
})
```

//home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Friend Finder Home Page</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="rowOne">
        <div class="jumbotron col-lg-6">
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <p>Click the button NOW!</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">CLICK NOW!</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/survey.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can serve a js file in the same way as you are doing with your HTML file: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html